# How to get data by status field in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, rest

Actually I'm working on a project.I want to get data by status field not by id which is created in models.py in Django rest framework.
Here this is my scource code
**Models.py file**

```
class employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

> 

**Views.py** file

```
class employeeviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = models.employee.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.employeeserializer
class employeebystatus(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   def get(self, request, status):
       employee = models.employee.objects.filter(status=status)
       if employee:
           serializer = serializers.employeeserializer(employee, many=True)
           return Response(status=200, data=serializer.data)
       return Response(status=400, data={'Employee Not Found'})
```

> 

**Urls.py**file

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('employee/<status>/', employeeviewset)
```

How to get data by status field using queries can any one tell me the answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to get your view to return instances of your Employee model by filtering based on status instead of user_id. If that is correct, you should be able to update your urls.py file to this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('employee/', employeeviewset)
router.register('employee/<status>', employeebystatus)
```

Comment: It will raise an error    AssertionError: `basename` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.

Comment: Have you actually tried providing the basename argument or adding a queryset attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Query to get specific data as per user requested from url path

```
ModelName.objects.get(ColumnName="status")
```

> You can also try

```
class StatusAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self,request):
        XYZ = ModelName.objects.get(ColumnName="status")
        serializer = YourSerializeNAme(XYZ,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```